# Excel To Object

Tags: excel

I have a project in asp.net mvc that upload excel file into action.I am going to directly read data from  HttpPostedFileBase as FileStream and convert it to object without saving file in server.

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult AddBulkIndividual(HttpPostedFileBase file)
    {
            Application excel = new Application();
            excel.Visible = false;
            excel.Workbooks.Open(filePath);
            _Workbook workbook = excel.ActiveWorkbook;
            _Worksheet worksheet = workbook.ActiveSheet;
```

.....

what can i put instead filepath to read from filestream directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe the default Excel library can read a file from a stream. You could possibly write the stream to a file first and open that, or use a library like [ExcelDataReader](http://exceldatareader.codeplex.com/).

If you need to do a ton more with the Excel format, I'd check out [OfficeWriter](http://www.officewriter.com), which can open from streams plus much more. It is probably overkill for your needs, however. Disclaimer: I'm one of the engineers who built a prior version.

Comment: I used ExcelDataReader and i gave it filestream as method parameter whitout save into file!